# I got the error FatalThrowableError Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Http\Request::merge() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a registration form with two factor authentication with Google Authenticator. While I try to register a new user Account and after scan the generated QR code then press the complete registration button, I just got an error

> FatalThrowableError  Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Http\Request::merge() must be of the type array, null
>   given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\repository\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php
>   on line 113

This is my register controller

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        //first we will validate the incoming request
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        // Initialise the 2FA class
        $google2fa = app('pragmarx.google2fa');
        // store registration data in an array
        $registration_data = $request->all();
        // Create new secret key to the registration data
        $registration_data["google2fa_secret"] = $google2fa->generateSecretKey();
        // store registration data to the user session for new request
        $request->session()->flash('registration_data', $registration_data);
        // Create the QR image. 
        $QR_Image = $google2fa->getQRCodeInline(
            config('app.name'),
            $registration_data['email'],
            $registration_data['username'],
            $registration_data['google2fa_secret']
        );
        // Send the QR barcode image to our view
        return view('google2fa.register', ['QR_Image' => $QR_Image, 'secret' => $registration_data['google2fa_secret']]);
    }
    public function completeRegistration(Request $request) 
    {
        // add the session data back to the request input
        $request->merge(session('registration_data')); <- I got error because of this line (in line 113)
        // Call the default laravel authentication
        <br>return $this->registration($request);
    }
```

and this is the route address

`Route::get('/complete-registration', 'Auth\RegisterController@completeRegistration');`

I have already inputed method completeRegistration in register controller above

Comment: the error is pretty clear: session('registration_data') is null and it must be an array. By the way calling the array_merge function with 1 parameter is useless

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` condition to check whether `registration_data` is empty or not.

```
if (session('registration_data') != '' && session('registration_data') != null)
{
    $request->merge(session('registration_data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this

```
$request->merge(['registration_date'=>session('registration_data')]);
```